# How to correct a type object error

Tags: c++

This is my code for one of the classes unforunately I keep getting an error saying that 'weapon is not a type' which I'm aware of just uncertain of what type this would be.

knight.h

```
  1 #ifndef KNIGHT_H
  2 #define KNIGHT_H
  3 
  4 using namespace std;
  5 
  6 class knight
  7 {
  8   private:
  9     string name;
 10     int stamina;
 12     weapon weapon_in_hand(string weapon_type, int sr, int hc);*The problem is here*
 13 
 14   public:
 15     void on_horse();
 16     knight(string name, int stamina, string weapon_type, int sr,int hc);
 17     bool hit();
 18     void unhorse_yourself();
 19     bool are_you_exhausted();
 20     void display();
 21 };
 22 #endif
~                                                                               
"knight.h" 22L, 418C                                          1,1           All
```

and this what it connects to

```
 25 bool hit()
 26 {
 27   stamina=stamina-weapon_in_hand.stamina_required();
 28   if(weapon_in_hand.did_you_hit()==true)
 29     return true;
 30   else
 31     return false;
 32 knight::knight(string n, int st, string weapon_type, int sr,int hc)
 33   :name(n), stamina(st), weapon_in_hand(weapon_type, sr, hc)
 34 {
 35 }
```

Comment: You'll have to declare a weapon as a class, I think.

Comment: I assume `weapon` is also supposed to be a class?

Comment: It would be helpful if you at least specified what programming language you are using (in the tags). Even though it is pretty self-evident.

Comment: it looks like weapon is a class not a data type. Do you have a class for Weapon?

Comment: @Dan the #indef makes it appear to be C++

Comment: @Sorceri yes it is self-evident (as stated in my comment) but for tagging/search purposes it should be stated.

Comment: @Dan sorry missed the last line of: self-evident ;)

Answer (score 3):

The error here is that you haven't declared what a weapon is.

Do you have a header file that you forgot to include?

The compiler starts over for each .c/.cpp file you write, so make sure you #include headers to get the type definitions you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The type `weapon` is not defined. You must include weapon.h at the top of knight.h (right before the using). If this doesn't exist, you have to create this class.